# Appending Django HTTP Proxy URLs

Tags: python, django, proxy, url-pattern

I'm using this django app:
http://httpproxy.yvandermeer.net/

I'm using it to make requests to an external api, and it's working fine, however I'd like to modify the URL pattern and I'm not having much success.

In urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^api/(?P<url>.*)$', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
)
```

And I'm making an AJAX request like so:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://siteaddress.com/api/search/?query1={{ model.field1 }}&key=123456789",
....
```

As you can see, my API key is being displayed publicly on the front-end with my ajax call. I'd like to append it to the url pattern in urls.py, but it isn't working.

I've tried:

```
(r'^api/(?P<url>.*)$&key=123456789', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
(r'^api/(?P<url>.*)&key=123456789$', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
(r'^api/(?P<url>.*.&key=123456789)$', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
(r'^api/(?P<url>.*)$.&key=123456789', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
```

But none of those seem to work.  Can I append the key to the end of this url pattern or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Django docs:

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name.

You can't put GET parameters inside url regexp.